# Is it possible to import gconf xml into dconf? (generally or just for gnome-terminal)

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, dconf, gconf

I installed 16.04 on a new machine. I'd like to migrate some, but not all, config from my 15.10 setup to it.

The immediate goal is to migrate gnome-terminal config from .gconf/apps/gnome-terminal-2.

15.10 used xml-backed gconf. 16.10 uses dconf. How can I convert/import gconf xml files into dconf?

Answer (score 1):

1. By using gconf-editor and dconf-editor. Open both editors and manually update all settings you want. Since you say that you want migrate only some settings this might be your only option.
2. By writing small application / script that reads settings from gconf and then sets them in dconf.